# NoMethodError working with two models in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller, nomethoderror

I have a rating system for real estate agents. I have an agent model and an agent_review model. The rating is stored in the agent_review table, but I need to display the average rating in a view under the agent model and am running into some issue. All code is posted below, please and thank you in advance.

agent model:

```
has_many :agent_reviews
```

agent_review model:

```
belongs_to :agent
```

agent view:

```
<h3>Agent Rating: <%= @agent.agent_reviews.rating %> (<%= @agent.agent_reviews.count %>)</h3>
```

agent controller show method:

```
def show
    @agent_reviews = AgentReview.all
    @agent = Agent.find_by_slug(params[:id]) || Agent.find(params[:id])

    if @agent.private_profile? && !current_agent&.super_admin?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "That user has a private profile"
    else
      @favorite_listings =   @agent.liked_listings.available.includes(:neighborhood)
      @agent_listings = @agent.sales_agent_listings.available.visible
      @mate_posts = @agent.liked_mates.order(:when)

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @agent }
      end
    end
  end
```

error:

[image]

Comment: Show the full error log from your terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@agent.agent_reviews` is an Active Record relationship - there is no 'rating' for that, since it's more than one `agent_review` object (the fact that it's plural should tell you that).

So if an agent has 6 reviews, with ratings that vary from 1 to 5, you want to show the average of those.  You need to add the following to the `agent.rb` model file:

```
def average_rating
  if self.agent_reviews.any?
    sum = 0
    self.agent_reviews.each do |agent_review|
      sum += agent_review.rating
    end
    return sum/self.agent_reviews.count
  else
    return nil    # agent has no reviews, don't divide by zero!
  end
end
```

*(that's more verbose than it needs to be, you could condense it with some SQL magic)*

And reference that new method in your view:

```
<h3>Agent Rating: <%= @agent.average_rating %> (<%= @agent.agent_reviews.count %>)</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Jhon Feltz answer, you can to do this in a short mode. Like this:

```
def average_rating
    agent_reviews = self.agent_reviews
    agent_reviews.any? ? (agent_reviews.map(&:rating).sum / agent_reviews.count) : nil
end
```